# $\{x: x^T Ax = a\}$ is unbounded for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then A is indefinite

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A_{3\times 3}$ be symmetric matrix.
>
> If set $\{x: x^T Ax = a\}$ is unbounded for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then
>   A is indefinite.

Let's take $a=1$. We are told that there is at least 1 x such that solves $x^T Ax = 1$, hence A is not negative semidefinite. Analogously, take $a = -1$, i.e. A is not positive semidefinite. A matrix that is neither positive semidefinite, nor negative semidefinite is called indefinite.

My question: if my solution is correct, then why do I need to know that the set $\{x: x^T Ax = a\}$ is unbounded?

Comment: How do you know that there is an $x$ solving $x^TAx=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it seems that everything works if we replace the word "unbounded" by "non-empty" and of course by homogeneity we may only assume it for $a\in\{-1,1\}$.